# react project compiled successfully but dont show on browser

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

I did several react projects before but it is the first time I
encountered this problem.
After I ran

npx create-react-app myapp
cd myapp

I created a react project, then I ran

npm start

It looks very fine:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D3dUs.png)

However, the project did not show in the browser, when I go to the localhost:3000 it reminds me "This site can’t be reached":

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2jFRX.png)

I tried to change the port but no matter what I do, this situation still lasts. The environment is good, the computer is good, the nodejs is good, anyone has encountered this kind of situation before can give me some advice? Thanks!

Comment: try with the  apple-darwin... link in the first image

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because of the env variable `HOST`.

To fix that you need to add `HOST="localhost"` to your `~.bash_profile` file, and then reload the env variables using `source ~/.bash_profile`. (don't forget to restart your server)

This should fix your problem.

Comment: hey bro thanks for your answer. Please help me further. I do not know how to access the b .bash_profile. File.

Comment: The .bash_profile is usually in the home directory, you can access it using `~`
For example if you want to modify it using nano, you would open it using this command: `nano ~/.bash_profile`